# Rolling for Horror Between Rooms with No Door

Tags: mansions-of-madness

The setup for Story 2 contains adjacent rooms with no wall or door.  The rules say that you must roll for horror when entering a room with a monster or when a monster enters the room.  My assumption is that applies in the case where there is a clear line of site since the rules specify "room".

However, I just wanted to know if anyone could verify that even if there is a line of site between 2 rooms, you only do the horror role when in the same room as a monster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules clearly state that you roll a Horror Test, when a monster enters a room with an investigator or visa versa (page 15). Line of Sight has nothing to do with the question, you do not roll a Horror Test, because you can see a monster.

> Room - An area of the map tile that has a name and is separated from the other rooms by solid brown walls, doors, or the edge of the map tile. ... (page 8)
>
> Whenever a monster enters (or is placed in) an investigator’s room (or vice versa), the investigator must immediately make an attribute test called a HORROR TEST. He does so by making a Willpower test modified by the monster’s horror rating (the blue number at the top of its monster token). If he fails this test, he takes one horror (see “Damage and Horror” on page 24)

Answer (score 0):

I think I saw in a faq that in regards to fire they would count as two rooms and I  have played the horror rules the same way.  When it comes to shooting though I have used normal LOS rules.